# How to access to numbers from *.txt file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, text, file-io, numbers, textreader

I have a data.txt file like:

123 124 125 126

I want to compare these number against num

My code is like this

```
 data= textread('data.txt','%d');
    num = 125;
    if num == data
         b = 1;
    else
         b = 0;
    end
```

but answer shows 0 ( b = 0 )

how to scan these numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from the doc page of [`eq`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) function (the functional form of `==` operator):

> ```
> A == B
> ```
>
> If one input is scalar and the other a nonscalar array, then the
>   scalar input is treated as if it were an array having the same
>   dimensions as the nonscalar input array. In other words, if input A is
>   the number 100, and B is a 3-by-5 matrix, then A is treated as if it
>   were a 3-by-5 matrix of elements, each set to 100. MATLAB returns an
>   array of the same dimensions as the nonscalar input array.

And here is the relevant section from the docs of [`if`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) statement:

> ```
> if expression
>     statements
> end
> ```
>
> An evaluated expression is true when the result is nonempty and
>   contains all nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise,
>   the expression is false.

So perhaps you meant to use:

```
if any(data == num)
    disp('number found')
end
```